# How to find statistical significance between binned data in R?

Tags: r, anova

I have a dataset that looks likes this:

```
'data.frame':   18 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ vd : Factor w/ 2 levels "n","y"
 $ aud: Factor w/ 3 levels "C","E","N"
 $ Class   : Factor w/ 3 levels "0-80","80-1000",">1000"
 $ prop    : num  0.0664546900 0.9262321145 0.0073131955 0.0620561902 0.9376350726 0.0003087373 0.0349832527 0.9646445850 0.0003721623 0.0242171190 0.9572025052 0.0185803758 0.0143244290 0.9804490902 0.0052264808 0.0272856852 0.9698635716 0.0028507432
```

Is there any significance among three aud levels (i.e., C, E, N) in different "Class" (i.e., 0-80, 80-1000, >1000, and whether the significance will be modulated by the vd levels (i.e, n, y)?

How to do it in R?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you seek recommendations for statistical methods to test an hypothesis, then you should ask such questions over at [stats.se] instead. You are more likely to get better answers there. Once you know what test you want to perform, then you search how to do that in R. Then, if you still can't find an answer, then you might ask here. But first you need to know what's statistically appropriate for your data.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I will move the question to Cross Validated.